# Only show Bootstrap navbar on mobile.

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I am bit of a noob when it comes to bootstrap but what I am trying to do is have a side menu when in desktop or tablet mode and a fixed top navbar in mobile view.

I am reverse engineering a simple theme http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/sb-admin/

I have removed everything from the bar I just can't get it to dissapear in non mobile resolutions. I'm sure I am being stupid, thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Bootstrap's [responsive utilities](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities)

With these you can give the navbar a class of `visible-xs` which would only show up on devices with a resolution less than 768px.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, thats super helpful. When I use that it makes my side bar disappear on those resolutions as well, this is because its under the top navbar div obviously. How do I go about putting the sidebar outside of that div and have it work still?

Comment: You're going to have to write your own media queries to accomplish that behavior.